# When element got visible in Javascript it toggle back to hidden

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Please help as when ever i clcik and call Javascript function to unhide an element it turn back hidden again. it takes a second or less.

HTML

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFromCalOpen" Width = "35" runat="server" Text="&gt;"  style="display:none; visibility:hidden;"  OnClientClick ="ShowCal()"  />
```

Javascript

```
function ShowCal() {

var elem = document.getElementById('MainContent_CalendarFrom');

if (elem.visibility = "hidden" ) {
    alert("Show");
    elem.style.visibility = "visible";
    elem.style.display = "inline";
}
else {
    alert("Hide");
    elem.style.visibility = "hidden";
    elem.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

it like when ever i click on the button it refresh its style properties of all elements

Please help

Comment: That isn't HTML, it is ASP.NET. If you have a client side issue, then please execute the server side code and show us the *output*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error/bug on your code here

```
if (elem.visibility = "hidden" ) {
```

you not check for the if, but you set it hidden !

To avoid this kind of errors try this way / trick

```
if ("hidden" == elem.visibility ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Two major problems in your code.

1. `elem.visibility` is not an attribute of your object.  If you want to look at the style setting, it would be `elem.style.visibility`.
2. A comparison is done with `==` or `===`, not with `=`.  You were doing an assignment operation with `=`.

Try this code:

```
function ShowCal() {

    var elem = document.getElementById('MainContent_CalendarFrom');

    if (elem.style.visibility == "hidden" ) {
        alert("Show");
        elem.style.visibility = "visible";
        elem.style.display = "inline";
    }
    else {
        alert("Hide");
        elem.style.visibility = "hidden";
        elem.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

FYI, there's no need to set both `style.visibility` and `style.display`.  If you're going to set style.display to "none", then the visibility setting isn't needed.

A simpler version of your code would be this (which you can see working [here in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sVEKu/)):

```
function ShowCal() {

    var elem = document.getElementById('MainContent_CalendarFrom');

    if (elem.style.display == "none" ) {
        elem.style.display = "inline";
    } else {
        elem.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

And, remove the `visibility: hidden` from the HTML for this tag.  The `display: none` is all you need.

For reference (in case this is a possibility), this is one of those places that libraries like jQuery or YUI are handy.  In jQuery this would just be:

```
function ShowCal() {
    $("#MainContent_CalendarFrom").toggle();
}
```